# Find who started the build in Jenkins and take some action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to execute a set of steps based on who starts the build. For e.g, if user A starts the build in Jenkins then I need to call pgmA in Jenkins and if user B starts the build I need to call pgmB.

Is there any plugin or any other way which will help me identify who started the build?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have 2 builds and tell the people who should be using which one?

Comment: Yes. TWo jobs doing the same thing is waste of resources

Comment: I don't understand. What are doing that's the same? The question states they're doing different things based on the user. Also, developer time (that is, your time) is a resource. =) Does your time cost more than the resources you're trying to save?

Comment: Well.. there is a whole of checkout and build before I take the path of pgmA or pgmB. That process takes 2 hours. I don't want to repeat that twice

Comment: Have you considered dependent builds? That might work for you. One build would do most of the work, another build would depend on it and be started automatically by Jenkins when appropriate, and a last build could depend on the first built and be started by users. I think that might be the only way to actually save work, anyway. If you're just detecting who started it, all that work would be repeated for each build regardless of who started it; right?

Answer (score 2):

In the Jenkins UI, the reason a build was started is shown on the

```
http://jenkinshost/job/jobname/buildnumber
```

page.  Note that builds can be started in multiple ways:

- Manually by a user
- By an SCM change
- Triggered by an upstream build
- Triggered by the scheduler

So there isn't a single place where you can see *who* triggered the build.

If you want to get the information programatically, take a look at `http://jenkinshost/job/jobname/buildnumber/api`